# How to implement horizontal line with custom textview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-linearlayout, textview

I want to implement two horizontal line side by side and a custom textview in between those lines (exactly like the pic shown below)

[image]

I wrote the following code to implement the horizontal line

```
 <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/green" />
```

Plz help me to create that custom text showing "OR" in between those lines. what should be the design approach? shall i use an imageview ?

Comment: maybe you can use somthing like `<LinearLayout orientation:horizontal> <View height:1dp><imageView src:ORImage><View height:1dp>`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating it as an image resource, and using an imageview instead of a textview.  It would make things much easier for you.

I would suggest creating a medium density and high density version of the image though and placing them in the appropriate folders in your res folder.

```
/res/drawable-mdpi (put medium density image here)
/res/drawable-hdpi (put high density image here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use following with `TextView`

> drawable_or_bg.xml

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="2"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <solid android:color="#YOUR_COLOR" />
    </shape>
```

set it as background to `TextView`

**Don't use image approche As image required for every density it will increase size of APK by atleast some bytes**